# What is the data format layout for txindex LevelDB values?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, database, txindex

The keys I understand, `t` + 32-byte hash.

But my problem are the values. I understand from sources such as [What are the keys used in the blockchain levelDB (ie what are the key:value pairs)?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/what-are-the-keys-used-in-the-blockchain-leveldb-ie-what-are-the-keyvalue-pair) that the values should encode three values: dat file number, block offset, and tx offset within block.

But I've noticed that each value has a different sizes between 5 and 10 on the first thousand entries, so I'm not sure how to decode the values into those three fields. Are those fields simply 3 varint values?

Here's my Plyvel code that prints out the lengths using plyvel==1.5.1, Bitcoin Core v26.0.0 on Ubuntu 23.10:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import struct

import plyvel

def decode_varint(data):
    """
    https://github.com/alecalve/python-bitcoin-blockchain-parser/blob/c06f420995b345c9a193c8be6e0916eb70335863/blockchain_parser/utils.py#L41
    """
    assert(len(data) > 0)
    size = int(data[0])
    assert(size <= 255)

    if size < 253:
        return size, 1

    if size == 253:
        format_ = '<H'
    elif size == 254:
        format_ = '<I'
    elif size == 255:
        format_ = '<Q'
    else:
        # Should never be reached
        assert 0, "unknown format_ for size : %s" % size

    size = struct.calcsize(format_)
    return struct.unpack(format_, data[1:size+1])[0], size + 1

ldb = plyvel.DB('/home/ciro/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/indexes/txindex/', compression=None)
i = 0
for key, value in ldb:
    if key[0:1] == b't':
        txid = bytes(reversed(key[1:])).hex()
        print(i)
        print(txid)
        print(len(value))
        print(value.hex(' '))
        value = bytes(reversed(value))
        file, off = decode_varint(value)
        blk_off, off = decode_varint(value[off:])
        tx_off, off = decode_varint(value[off:])
        print((txid, file, blk_off, tx_off))
        print()
        i += 1
```

but it eventually blows up at:

```
131344
ec4de461b0dd1350b7596f95c0d7576aa825214d9af0e8c54de567ab0ce70800
7
42 ff c0 43 8b 94 35
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ciro/bak/git/bitcoin-strings-with-txids/./tmp.py", line 39, in <module>
    blk_off, off = decode_varint(value[off:])
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ciro/bak/git/bitcoin-strings-with-txids/./tmp.py", line 29, in decode_varint
    return struct.unpack(format_, data[1:size+1])[0], size + 1
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes
```

So I wonder if I guessed the format wrong, or if it's just a bug in my code.

Comparing to: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Variable_length_integer I would decode:

```
42 ff c0 43 8b 94 35
```

manually as:

- 42
- ff: expect 8 bytes next

  - c0 43 8b 94 35: only 5 bytes left, blowup

I also tried to inverse value:

```
value = bytes(reversed(value))
```

but then it blows up very early, definitely wrong.

I also tried to ignore the error to see if there are others, but there were hundreds them, so something is definitely wrong with my method.

Related:

- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1068721.0

**Update**

Given Antoine's answer, I've updated my code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import struct

import plyvel

def decode_varint(data):
    i = 0
    ret = 0
    while True:
        b = data[i]
        ret += b & 0x7F
        if b & 0x80:
            b += 1
        else:
            return (ret, i + 1)
        ret <<= 7
        i += 1

ldb = plyvel.DB('/home/ciro/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/indexes/txindex/', compression=None)
i = 0
nerrs = 0
for key, value in ldb:
    if key[0:1] == b't':
        if i % 1000000 == 0:
            print(i//1000000)
        txid = bytes(reversed(key[1:])).hex()
        print(value.hex(' '))
        total_off = 0
        file, off = decode_varint(value)
        total_off += off
        blk_off, off = decode_varint(value[total_off:])
        total_off += off
        tx_off, off = decode_varint(value[total_off:])
        total_off += off
        assert total_off == len(value)
        print((txid, file, blk_off, tx_off))
        i += 1
print(f'nerrs: {nerrs}')
```

and all length asserts seem to pass which is promising. However, when I tried to verify the first few values:

```
93 1a 96 8c e7 74 a7 bb 0a
('d176d4960a78b41971f9d19207b59af6584b16ef323de55e983aec0100000000', 2458, 46347252, 646538)
93 1a aa d0 f0 72 86 90 01
('4d19a5ba6a5455a6d4d46d6999fb0a4a7b29e603fe229cd4f1a34d0300000000', 2458, 89405554, 100353)
93 1e d4 cf 18 82 be 76
('ba75d6ac075959632d9e012f0321c367a54e9f2bde2e2bebce6baa0300000000', 2462, 1386392, 40822)
93 18 a8 96 8e 5a 8a d3 14
('7df98bab9d89fc14d0dec365fa124b3e112017c6b8f56f64cf159e0600000000', 2456, 84248410, 174484)
```

I didn't find a match between:

```
bitcoin-core.cli getrawtransaction d176d4960a78b41971f9d19207b59af6584b16ef323de55e983aec0100000000
tail -c+$((46347252 + 646538 - 1)) ~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/blocks/blk02458.dat  | head -c 2000 | xxd -p | tr -d '\n'

bitcoin-core.cli getrawtransaction 4d19a5ba6a5455a6d4d46d6999fb0a4a7b29e603fe229cd4f1a34d0300000000
tail -c+$((89405554 + 100353 - 1)) ~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/blocks/blk02458.dat  | head -c 2000 | xxd -p | tr -d '\n'

bitcoin-core.cli getrawtransaction ba75d6ac075959632d9e012f0321c367a54e9f2bde2e2bebce6baa0300000000
tail -c+$((89405554 + 100353 - 1)) ~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/blocks/blk02462.dat  | head -c 2000 | xxd -p | tr -d '\n'
```

so either my parsing or my checks are wrong somehow.

I've searched for the bytes that `getrawtransactions` gave me for d176d4960a78b41971f9d19207b59af6584b16ef323de55e983aec0100000000 using `bgrep`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223078/best-way-to-grep-a-big-binary-file/758528#758528 and found it at:

```
~/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/blocks/blk02586.dat: 02ed92ce
```

and offset 0x02ed92ce = 49124046, so these would be the expected correct values for this one.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the `VarInt` and `CompactSize` encoding. `CompactSize` encoding (also confusingly referred to as "varint" outside Bitcoin Core) is used in the Bitcoin protocol. `VarInt` encoding is internal to Bitcoin Core and used as a more compact encoding in the internal database.

See [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/114585/101498) for details about the `VarInt` format:

> Variable-length integers: bytes are a MSB base-128 encoding of the number. The high bit in each byte signifies whether another digit follows. To make sure the encoding is one-to-one, one is subtracted from all but the last digit. Thus, the byte sequence a[] with length len, where all but the last byte has bit 128 set, encodes the number:
>
> ```
> (a[len-1] & 0x7F) + sum(i=1..len-1, 128^i*((a[len-i-1] & 0x7F)+1))
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've updated my code on the question, and it does seem to extract 3 integers correctly from every value as expected. However, I was not able to actually find the transactions at those offsets as explained in the question now, I wonder what I'm doing wrong.